# Flatten array of regular expressions

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match-all

I have an array of regular expressions -$toks:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /(?=\D*\d)/
    [1] => /\b(waiting)\b/i
    [2] => /^(\w+)/
    [3] => /\b(responce)\b/i
    [4] => /\b(from)\b/i
    [5] => /\|/
    [6] => /\b(to)\b/i
)
```

When I'm trying to flatten it:

```
$patterns_flattened = implode('|', $toks);
```

I get a regex:

```
/(?=\D*\d)/|/\b(waiting)\b/i|/^(\w+)/|/\b(responce)\b/i|/\b(from)\b/i|/\|/|/\b(to)\b/i
```

When I'm trying to:

```
if (preg_match('/'. $patterns_flattened .'/', 'I'm waiting for a response from', $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);  
}
```

- I get an error:

  Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier '(' in ...index.php on line

Where is my mistake?
Thanks.

Comment: Your regular expression needs to be between //, so you need to remove // from each value of array, also remove "i" which means case insensitive, and put it after //i, and all data from array implode between /implode()/i

Comment: @user889349 Why not loop array and test each regex?

Comment: @splash58 That would be a lot slower, IMHO

Comment: but OP now should be sure that removing options such as `/i` does not  change a logic of regex.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the opening and closing slashes, like this:

```
$toks = [
    '(?=\D*\d)',
    '\b(waiting)\b',
    '^(\w+)',
    '\b(response)\b',
    '\b(from)\b',
    '\|',
    '\b(to)\b',
];
```

And then, I think you'll want to use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`:

```
$patterns_flattened = implode('|', $toks);
if (preg_match_all("/$patterns_flattened/i", "I'm waiting for a response from", $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

If you get the first element instead of all elements, it'll return the whole matches of each regex:

```
Array
(
    [0] => I
    [1] => waiting
    [2] => response
    [3] => from
)
```

[Try it on 3v41.org](https://3v4l.org/Gq8XG)

Answer (score 2):

```
   <?php

$data = Array
(
0 => '/(?=\D*\d)/',
1 => '/\b(waiting)\b/i',
2 => '/^(\w+)/',
3 => '/\b(responce)\b/i',
4 => '/\b(from)\b/i',
5 => '/\|/',
6 => '/\b(to)\b/i/'
);


$patterns_flattened = implode('|', $data);

$regex = str_replace("/i",'',$patterns_flattened);
$regex = str_replace('/','',$regex);

if (preg_match_all(  '/'.$regex.'/', "I'm waiting for a responce from", $matches)) {
    echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

You have to remove the slashes from your regex and also the `i` parameter in order to make it work. That was the reason it was breaking.

A really nice tool to actually validate your regex is this :

[https://regexr.com/](http://regex%20tool)

I always use that when i have to make a bigger than usual regular expression.

The output of the above code is :

```
  Array
(
    [0] => I
    [1] => waiting
    [2] => responce
    [3] => from
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few adjustments to make with your `$tok` array.

1. To remove the error, you need to remove the pattern delimiters and pattern modifiers from each array element.
2. None of the capture grouping is necessary, in fact, it will lead to a higher step count and create unnecessary output array bloat.
3. Whatever your intention is with `(?=\D*\d)`, it needs a rethink.  If there is a number anywhere in your input string, you are potentially going to generate lots of empty elements which surely can't have any benefit for your project.  [Look at what happens](https://regex101.com/r/oQ9oSi/1) when I put a space then `1` after `from` in your input string.

Here is my recommendation: ([PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/knAE5))

```
$toks = [
    '\bwaiting\b',
    '^\w+',
    '\bresponse\b',
    '\bfrom\b',
    '\|',
    '\bto\b',
];

$pattern = '/' . implode('|', $toks) . '/i';
var_export(preg_match_all($pattern, "I'm waiting for a response from", $out) ? $out[0] : null);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'I',
  1 => 'waiting',
  2 => 'response',
  3 => 'from',
)
```